# Rails has_many through validation got skipped

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, activerecord

I'm feeling a little bit dumb to ask this, but I've been Googling my a*# off.

Well I have the following models:

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :employments
  has_many :users, through: :employments

  validates_presence_of :name
  validates_presence_of :description
  validates_numericality_of :zip, only_integer: true
  validates_presence_of :email
  validates_presence_of :street
  validates_presence_of :city
  validates_presence_of :country
  validates_presence_of :telephone
end

class Employment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :company
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :employments
  has_many :companies, through: :employments
end
```

Important here is the company-Model which has some validations.

Now, I have the following Controller to create a new Company:

```
class CompaniesController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @company = Company.new(company_params) # The params were set with a private Method
    @employment = @company.employments.build(user: current_user, is_admin: true)
    if @employment.save
      redirect_to :back, flash: { success: 'Success' }
    else
      @title = 'Create a new company'
      render :new
    end
  end
end
```

The Problem is, that when I leave the companies-Fields blank, the company gets not created, but the employment-Model gets persistet in the Database.

I believe It has something to do with the Company.new()-Call I have to check, if the @company-Model gets created first, before the @employment-Model gets created.

How can I achieve that the validation gets tested first?

Thank you very much!

Comment: in addition to vinodadhikary's answer, you can also try saving the company. so instead of `@employment.save`, use `@company.save`.  That should also save `@employment` when `@company` passes validations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To validate associated object you need to use [validates_associated](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates_associated).  Please note the "Warning" and "Note" in the linked api document.

Try:

```
class Employment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :company

  validates_associated :company
end
```

Answer (score 1):

in addition to vinodadhikary's answer, you can also try saving the company. so instead of `@employment.save`, use `@company.save`. That should also save `@employment` when `@company` passes validations.